# How Can I Create Android Java In-App Notification?

Tags: java, android, mobile, mobile-development

I use Android java.

[image]

For example: I have a notification like this when navigating within the app. It is independent from Android notifications, like within the instagram and within the twitter.

Let's assume that normally the display time of this notification is 3 seconds. I am in activity A, if I go to activity B when the notification arrives, the notification disappears from the screen before it expires. So I can't keep this notification live on the screen as I move between activities. It will disappear before it expires.

What will I do to not lose this fragment while navigating between activities. And what will I do to make it work on each activity. I have no idea about this, I am looking for a way.

Right now it only works correctly when the notification comes when I am in the current activity, but as soon as I move to another activity it disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I don't understand your question correctly but you could display it in the activity which holds the other fragments for the different pages. Then It would be there even if your change the other fragments.

Comment: I don't know how to do this. This is exactly what I want to tell you. If you receive a message from a friend while using Instagram, the notification that comes in Instagram does not disappear immediately, it has a certain time. for example 5 seconds. it disappears only within this time. but let's assume that there is 5 seconds in my application. if I switch between activities, the notification disappears before it expires. so I can't keep the notification in transitions between activities.

Comment: Yeah that's why you shouldn't use to many activities when you can use fragments of course it will be gone if you close the activity. What you've have to do is to use a activity which holds the fragments, the fragments have the logic for their functionality and the third fragment is also in that activity which will show the notification. I try to write a template for you

Comment: I'm waiting. I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Not beautiful, just an example...  also the notifications moves the other fragments down but that could be fixed easily. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U1FcCMq6QVSZJLXQVRDO6zj5t9gPQDAA/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: Thank you very much, I will look into it. I hope this will be a solution.

Comment: Well, there is one more problem :D I have 3 activities other than fragments. What am I going to do about it :D How can I show it in activities? Is there a solution to do this on all screens without any problems? If you use discord, can you add me? I really need that. id: kzmkbl

Comment: I can't add you because of your privacy settings. my username: donmarv

Comment: I understand you, that's fine, but do you have a solution? Unfortunately I couldn't find much about it, how can I show it on the activities.